# No USB ports working after Windows 7 update

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-update

After running Windows update, none of my USB ports are working. The wired mouse and keyboard won't light up. However, when I do a hard reboot, they both light up, until Windows loads then they are dead.

I'm able to hit <kbd>Del</kbd> and enter the BIOS, but once I'm in, nothing works again. I know enough about computers to build one, but this is beyond me.  How do I get into my registry or device manager if none of my peripherals work?  I'm also using a USB Wifi dongle, and have no access to the router for a LAN connection.

Comment: If the keyboard doesn't work in BIOS, it probably isn't a Windows Update issue. If you move the devices to different USB ports do they work?

Comment: I've tried all of the different ports with no luck.

Comment: Do you have a PS/2 mouse and keyboard lying around? If those work you can start making checks on your USB devices from within Windows.

Comment: negative, I'll be picking up an adapter soon.

Comment: Well a Windows 7 would not effect them while in BIOS.  So it wasn't the update that did this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are possible solutions to try:

1. In device manager uninstall every USB device and restart
2. rollback the windows update
3. boot with a live cd (e.g.: Ubuntu) to see if it a hardware issue or software.

In your case you'll have to find a PS2 keyboard. (If you still have this type of port.)
If not you won't be able to check solutions 1 or 2.

Comment: Looks like I'm picking up a usb to ps2 adapter on my way home from work :)

Comment: tried a PS2 adapter, neither mouse nor keyboard worked.  That tells me its not just the USB ports, but PS2 as well.  I can't get into my system to trouble shoot.  Your next solution was to boot with a live cd, like Ubuntu, right?

Comment: yes. you can use [UNetbooting](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable usb key.